# Elasticsearch multi-term aggregation, but between records

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a set of records in Elasticsearch, each record having some number of tags, i.e.:

```
    { id: 0, tags: ["ant", "bird", "dog", "fox"]},
    { id: 1, tags: ["cat", "fox", "goose", "horse"]},
    { id: 2, tags: ["ant", "bird", "cat", "eel", "fox", "goose", "horse"]},
    { id: 3, tags: ["ant", "eel", "goose", "horse"]},
    { id: 4, tags: ["ant", "bird", "cat", "eel", "fox"]},
    { id: 5, tags: ["ant", "bird", "cat", "eel", "fox"]},
    { id: 6, tags: ["bird", "cat", "dog", "eel", "fox", "goose"]},
    { id: 7, tags: ["ant", "cat", "eel", "fox", "horse"]},
    { id: 8, tags: ["ant", "cat", "dog", "eel", "fox", "horse"]}
```

I would like to do the equivalent of a multi_term aggregation, but on all the values of `tags`, rather than on separate fields.

So, if looking for three tags, the results would be:

```
    ...
    aggregations: {
        my_agg: {
            ....
            buckets: [
                { "key": ["ant", "cat", "eel"], ... "doc_count": 5 },
                { "key": ["ant", "cat", "fox"], ... "doc_count": 5 },
                { "key": ["ant", "eel", "fox"], ... "doc_count": 5 },
                { "key": ["cat", "eel", "fox"], ... "doc_count": 5 },
                { "key": ["ant", "bird", "fox"], ... "doc_count": 4 },
                { "key": ["ant", "bird", "fox"], ... "doc_count": 4 },
                { "key": ["ant", "eel", "horse"], ... "doc_count": 4 },
                { "key": ["bird", "cat", "eel"], ... "doc_count": 4 },
                { "key": ["bird", "cat", "fox"], ... "doc_count": 4 },
                { "key": ["cat", "fox", "horse"], ... "doc_count": 4 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Did you write any elasticsearch queries yet? Do you need some optimisation or a complete query for this?

Comment: I have not.  I am looking for the basics of how to do this - I don't see a way to do it myself, but I'm not an ES expert.

BTW, storing the data in a different format is definitely an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below to achieve what you're looking for.

```
POST /<your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            def tags = new ArrayList(doc['tags.keyword']);
            def combinations = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
              for (int j = i + 1; j < tags.size(); j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < tags.size(); k++) {
                  combinations.add([tags[i], tags[j], tags[k]]);
                }
              }
            }
            return combinations;
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```